# What is this matrix called? And why does this look symmetric?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to calculate QK^T by multiplying a specific matrix X by W_Q and W_K to create Q and K. Looking at the result, it is not a completely symmetric matrix, but it looks almost symmetric. What are these matrices called and why does this happen? Also, can we say that these matrices have properties similar to symmetric matrices?

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do here. What is the context? What exactly are the matrices you're multiplying together? Is there some defining property other than only having entries $0,1,2,3$? What sort of properties similar to those of symmetric matrices are you interested in?